# How do I make UIScrollView fit its parent frame in NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I created a `UIScrollView` in xib file, have some subviews and constraints in it.

Then add it to a view pragmatically.

```
    NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil];
self.scrollView = arr[0];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

The scrollView does add in the view, but it's frame or `contentSize` is always wrong, I try to reset its `contentSize` but didn't work.

It always can scroll horizontally. I want it resize like a `UIView` to fit its parent frame, hope someone can help me solve it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can add constraints  in xib and use show hide if you don't want to show scroll view at start or all the time.

Comment: actually i want to use the scrollView as a canvas like a backgroundView, because it's subView's height may beyond to the screen height, I hope it can scroll vertically but horizontally I hope it can fit its superview's width and  strictly follow the uiscrollView's constraints.

Comment: ok try @Jorn's answer if it isn't work comment here

Comment: doesn't work, I've tried to add 4 constraints in four direction. it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the storyboard, you could add constraints programmatically for leading, trailing, top and bottom:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[scrollview]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"scrollview":self.scrollView}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[scrollview]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"scrollview":self.scrollView}]];

[self.view updateConstraints];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: doesn't work, I've tried add top, leading, trainling, bottom constraints, seems the scrollView will fit its subView's frame prior. But if you change the scrollView to uiview it will fit perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Override following method and add your scrollview or update frame in it. This method called when all constraints applied on views.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

For prevent scrolling set content size 0 for that direction . for example

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500,0)];
```

This will allow just horizontal scrolling.

Comment: If I only set the contentSize, it won't scroll but the scrollView does not fit its parent's view,. If I reset both the uiscrollView's frame and contentSize, it can be scroll.

Comment: frame reseting is compulsory , but content size is just for preventing one side , if you want both sides you didn't need to set at all . i answers both separately because content size is for scrolling and frame is for display inside parent view

Comment: I want to the scrollView fit the superView's frame and strictly follow its subView's constraints.

Comment: you just need to add in superview , no need of constraints if you are setting frame correclty.

Comment: right, but if it's a scrollView, then its subView won't fit in the screen. That's the problem. I want the scrollView fit the screent like a uiview, But in real, some of its subviews are posited outside the screen, and I am sure the constraints is correct, when I change the uiscrollView to a UIView's subclass, all is correct.

Comment: are you adding subviews programatically ?

Comment: no, the subView in scrollView was added in xib file , the scrollView was added programatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97946/discussion-between-mohammad-ishaq-and-zedzhao).